# For a non-resident, Is it worth investing in a 401k?

Tags: united-states, 401k, non-resident, employer-match

I'm planning to stay in the U.S. for 3 to 5 years. My company offers a 4% match for 401k contributions. Is it worth investing in a 401k plan with all the fees and penalties? Or is there a better way to save?

Comment: So, if you put in 4% of your salary, the company matches with another 4%.  I gather the fees and penalties are not that bad (50%). It seems like free money for a little extra hassle (if you intend to withdraw it in 3 to 5 years), though it will depend on your tax rate...

Comment: also make sure you stay around long enough to be fully vested.

Comment: Let's assume that tax bracket is 20%

Comment: Have a look at: https://www.wellsfargo.com/investing/retirement/tools/401k-early-withdrawal-calculator/  That suggests that the total you must pay is 20% + 10% penalty = 30%... on the TOTAL withdrawal (your 4% plus your employers 4%).  I can't see a real negative.

Comment: @balki 20% now, 0% when you're back to your home country and 401k withdrawals is your only US-sourced income. Better pay 10% then than 20% now, no?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should fund the 401(k) and get the 4% matching because it's free money.

When you leave the US, patience is a virtue to get the money penalty-free:

1. Rollover to an IRA.
2. Take "[Substantially equal periodic payments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substantially_equal_periodic_payments)" for 5 years or until age 59 1/2, whichever is longer, to avoid the 10% penalty. A long payout time for someone starting out, but penalty-free.

Or you can take the 10% penalty and take out the money all at once. You'll still owe income tax in either case, something to keep in mind if an early withdrawal would put you into a higher tax bracket. Also see this article: [Can Foreigners Withdraw 401(k) Funds Early?](http://blogs.marketwatch.com/ask/2011/10/27/how-can-foreigners-withdraw-u-s-retirement-funds-early/)

Another thing to keep in mind is that you never know what might happen -- you could fall in love with the US (or someone in the US, [smiley face]), apply for residency, decide to stay a long time, and that 401(k) with the 4% matching might turn out to have been a very nice thing when you retire.

Comment: Where did the 5 years came from?